# Run a js script before phantom-html2pdf generate a pdf from html

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Hello there I would like some help regarding phantom-html2pdf module for node. I want to generate a pdf file from an html and for this purpose I use phantomjs and phantom-html2pdf. My code is:

```
var pdf = require('phantom-html2pdf');

exports.makePdf = function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("pdf function");

    console.log(req.body);

    var html = req.body.html,
        css = req.body.css,
        js = req.body.js;

    var options = {
        "html" : html,
        "css" : css,
        "js" : js,
        // "runnings" : "Path to runnings file. Check further below for explanation.",
        "deleteOnAction" : true
    };

    pdf.convert(options, function(result) {

        /* Using a buffer and callback */
        result.toBuffer(function(returnedBuffer) {});

        /* Using a readable stream */
        var stream = result.toStream();

        /* Using the temp file path */
        var tmpPath = result.getTmpPath();

        /* Using the file writer and callback */
        result.toFile("file.pdf", function() {});
    });
};
```

As options to the pdf.convert() I pass the html page, the css for that page and a js script which adds some additional html tags (with content). My problem is that the pdf which is created have the correct css rules from the external file but it lacks the dynamically added html tags of the js script (external file that I pass as options).

Could anyone help me with my problem?

Thank you all in advance.